# php : result not shown after search

Tags: php, mysql

The problem is , the result is not shown after search .. the search is done by using textform . the form can search based on multiple textform , is there anything wrong with my code ? still new to php

```
    $sql = "   SELECT jobseeker.*, jobseeker_pendidikan.kursus, jobseeker_pengalaman.jawatan
               FROM jobseeker INNER JOIN jobseeker_pendidikan
                   ON jobseeker.no_kp = jobseeker_pendidikan.no_kp JOIN jobseeker_pengalaman
                   ON jobseeker_pendidikan.no_kp = jobseeker_pengalaman.no_kp
                   WHERE jobseeker.status_kerja = 'pencari kerja' ".$str.$str_mukim.$str_jantina.$str_umur.$str_jawatan.$str_tarafpend.$str_kursus."";

    $sql_result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

    if (mysql_num_rows($sql_result)>0) {
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)){
         for($i = 0; $i < 0; $i++){
              //$i = 0;
?> 
  <tr valign="top">
    <td><?php echo ($i+1); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo displayNama(ucwords(stripslashes($row['nama'])), $row['no_kp']); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo ucwords(stripslashes($row['no_kp'])); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo stripslashes($row['alamat']); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo ucwords(stripslashes($row['jantina'])); ?></td>
  </tr>

<?php
        }   
      }  
  }
```

Comment: Specify that $str.$str_mukim.$str_jantina.$str_umur.$str_jawatan.$str_tarafpend.$str_kursus contains which type data?

Comment: first thing first, are getting any error in the query ? If not is the number of returned rows > 0 ?

Comment: You have a typo on your `for` loop. Should be `$i++` instead of `i++`

Comment: Please stop using **MySQL_***, it is depreciated. Check out MySQLi or PDO. MySQLi is almost identical to MySQL so the switch is easy to make.

Comment: `for($i = 0; $i < 0; i++){` won't run indeed (as it runs as long `$i < 0` which is never). What are you using it for anyway?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty i'm not getting any error , but it doesn't show any result ..
@Kannan here .. 
`$str_jawatan = "";
if(($_POST['txt_jawatan']) && ($_POST['txt_jawatan'] != '')){
 $str_jawatan = " AND ((jawatan) LIKE '%".addslashes($_POST['txt_jawatan'])."%' )";
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`` `for($i = 0; $i < 0; i++) `` won't run indeed (as it runs as long `$i < 0` which is never)

Rewrite your while loop to the following, assuming you want to number the rows:

```
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
   // No for loop

   // HTML what you already had here 

   $i++;
}
```